# how can I set the new head of a linked list after running the function?

Tags: python, linked-list

I wrote a solution to this question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/

```
def swapPairs(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:

    prev = head
    curr = head
    nex = head.next
    
    while nex:
        curr = nex
        curr.next = prev
        nex = nex.next.next
        prev.next = nex
        prev = curr.next
```

My question is how do I set 'head' in my code above, so that I can return it at the end of the function? Like in a basic example of [1,2,3,4] -> [2,1,4,3]; 2 is clearly the head, but how can I include this is my code?

I thought about doing "head = head.next" at the start or end of my function, but neither works in my mind. Because if I do it at the start, then it will mess with the function, and if I write this line at the end of the main function, head.next will be pointing at the wrong object (it would be pointing at '4' for the example given in the last paragraph)

Would a dummy node help in this case? I was thinking of writing "dummy.next = head.next" at the start. Then simply returning dummy.next

Comment: Add another variable that you assign before the loop. E.g `result = head.next if head and head.next else head` and return that variable in the end.

Comment: Didn't you forget a `return head` at the end of your function? That would solve your problem with `head = swapPairs(head)`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could be `head` or `head.next` depending on the length of the list.

Comment: Of course, it should. I don't understand your comment-

Comment: @Serge Ballesta - let's consider the example [1,2,3,4] (head is 1), after running this though the function, it becomes [2,1,4,3]. So now isn't head.next = 4?? But this is not correct, as I need to return 2!

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable, e.g. `result`:

```
def swapPairs(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    result = head.next if head and head.next else head

    prev = curr = head
    nex = head.next
    while nex:
        # ...

    return result
```

Or simplify your task, using recursion:

```
def swapPairs(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    if head and (n2 := head.next):
        head.next, n2.next = self.swapPairs(n2.next), head
        return n2
    return head
```

Comment: Schwobaseggl, apologies I am still relatively new to linked list. Is your solution the same as what I suggested in the last paragraph of my question? i.e. introducing a dummy node at the start and simply doing dummy.next=  head.next? And at the end returning dummy.next

Comment: I did not check your logic. But you know before the loop which node you will return in the end as the head of the changed list, so just store it in a variable. You will still need to check your logic.

Comment: Yes, exactly that I what I mean- storing it as a variable. Thanks.